# How can I draw from ImageData to canvas with zoom in Haxe?

Tags: javascript, haxe

Well, I fill ScreenBuffer:ImageData 480x360 and then want to draw it to the canvas 960x720. The task is to decrease the fillrate; the nowadays pixels are very small and we can make them bigger with some quality loss. I look for the operator with 2D-accelaration. But we can't write directly to `js.html.Image` and `ImageData` hasn't link to `js.html.Image`. I found an example for pure JS:

**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas**

However, it doesn't want to work in Haxe because there isn't 'zoom' element. And there is some information about restrictions in HTML at copying from one image to another.
Many thanks for answers!

Comment: "It doesn't want to work in Haxe because there isn't 'zoom' element." - Not really sure what you mean by that, could you elaborate?

Comment: Here is the string "var zoomctx = js.Browser.document.getElementById('zoom').getContext('2d');" The compiler writes "js.html.Element has no field getContext"

Answer (score 0):

> The compiler writes "js.html.Element has no field getContext"

`getElementById()`'s return type is the generic `js.html.Element` class. Since in your case, you know you're dealing with a `<canvas>`, you can safely cast it to [the more specific `CanvasElement`](https://api.haxe.org/js/html/CanvasElement.html). This then lets you call its [`getContext()` method](https://api.haxe.org/js/html/CanvasElement.html#getContext):

```
var canvas:CanvasElement = cast js.Browser.document.getElementById('zoom');
var zoomctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Comment: I tried your code. The compiler writes: `Type not found : CanvasElement`. The next version compiles and works, but canvas1 has the value null: `var canvas1 = cast js.Browser.document.getElementById('zoom'); if (canvas1 != null) {var zoomctx = canvas1.getContext('2d');}`

Comment: You need to import `CanvasElement` first (`js.html.CanvasElement`). However, that shouldn't cause it to be `null`. Are you sure your HTML is correct?

Comment: I've added `import js.html.CanvasElement;` and the string `var canvas1:CanvasElement = cast js.Browser.document.getElementById('zoom');` compiles but `canvas1` is equal to `null`. About HTML: Yes, I am quite sure

Comment: This code compiles and runs without errors. Thank you!